# Why can't I still access Skype log and cached files from the path?

Tags: skype

```
^2A2B03F255E4AAF23F20BA82231B3A825886C6AE724798DDB4^tfile_urlpv
```

How can I open these files above?
  That's  the path  `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\`

`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\live#3aSkypeUserName\media_messaging\media_cache_v3`

**I can only see the the pictures, no text messages and sent files were there.
How can I access these files also?**